Position is not a valid member of model "Workspace.Orchooselimbo"
local ProximityPrompt = script.Parent
ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(Player)
    wait(1) 
    Player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position = game.Workspace.Orchooselimbo.Position 
end)

This script comes from ThenRemember's rig. Orchooselimbo's script is the same except its swapped to ThenRemember.
The script files are in the correct destination I believe
ThenRemember > ProximityPrompt > Script
Orchooselimbo > ProximityPrompt > Script
Orchooselimbo is a rig, and basically i'm trying to teleport from "ThenRemember" to "Orchooselimbo"
using a proximity prompt. The prompt does appear but when I click it it does nothing.
Any idea how to fix this?
These are both rigs by the way
I tried changing some letters to capital ones and i tried changing the symbols.
Everything results in an error I do know how to fix, but this one just makes it so hard

The error is telling you that Models don't have a Position property.
If you want to move Models around, you can use the GetPivot() and PivotTo(CFrame) methods.
Try this:
    wait(1)
    local orchooseLimboModel : Model = game.Workspace.Orchooselimbo
    local targetPosition : CFrame = orchooseLimboModel:GetPivot()
    Player.Character:PivotTo(targetPosition)

